# Creating a start screen for a HTML5 Canvas Game?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Most of us know that HTML5 Canvas element is having much better support with these amazingly fast Javascript Engines from Firefox, Safari and Chrome.

So recently I have been experimenting with game development with Javascript and the Canvas, and I am wondering what would be a good approach to be creating a Start Screen for a Javascript Game.

So far, the only idea I have would be creating a UI before the game and stuff with Javascript and use Event Listeners to track the mouse and when they click buttons. But I'm not sure if this a wise thing to do.

What would a good way to go about a Starting Screen, etc. in a Javascript game? Any help would be useful, thanks!

**UPDATE: Thanks for the blazing fast reply(s)! A lot of you are suggesting placing a img until the game loads, etc. So do I need to write a asset manager or some sort - to check when all the images etc. are loaded?**

Comment: I don't know if you need to get that complex.  It sounds like you just want to show an intro screen, maybe with a title and some instructions.  Please see my updated answer below with code sample.  Good luck!

Comment: Yes, just a intro screen and stuff. I looked at your updated answer and it seems really simple! Thanks, I'll play around with it.

Comment: Great!  Please select my answer as correct (green check mark) if you use it.  I could really use the points!

Comment: Also, you DO understand that you need to reference the jQuery framework for my solution to work, right?  Instructions for that can be found here:  http://jquery.com/

Comment: Yes I do understand that, I have worked with jQuery many times before, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Populate a div tag with your splash screen.  Have it showing on page load and have your canvas hidden.  Add a 'start' button to the div tag and on it's click event, hide the splash screen div tag and show the canvas using either jQuery or classic JavaScript.

Here is some sample code using jQuery:

```
   <div id="SplashScreen">
<h1>Game Title</h1>
<input id="StartButton" type="button" value="Start"/>
</div>

<canvas id="GameCanvas" style="display: none;">Game Stuff</canvas>

<script>
    $("#StartButton").click(function () {
        $("#SplashScreen").hide();
        $("#GameCanvas").show();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple, use a regular HTML `img` that is located 'above' your canvas until everything is loaded / initialised.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function startGame() {
    alert('Are you sure you want to make a new Game?');
}
function continueGame() {
    alert('Continue Game?');
}
```

```css
body, button {
    color: blue;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: cursive;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Game Title</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Game Title</h1>
  <script src="script.js">startGame()</script>
  <button onclick="startGame()">New Game</button>
  <button onclick="continueGame()">Continue Game</button>
</body>
</html>
```